# Python | Можно ли задать переменную без её вызова

Tags: python

Могу ли я в `Python` создать переменную, скажем `value_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')`, но сделать так, чтобы, она не вызывалась к примеру там где она прописана (в начале кода), а там где я её вызову. Если есть такая возможность подскажите, пожалуйста, как её реализовать.
Вот код

```py
dia = None

def question2():
    value_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
    value_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')

def question1():
    dia = input("Выберите действие: 1 - сложить, 2 - вычесть, 3 - умножить, 4 -разделить,\
    5 - возвести в степень, 6 - вычесть остаток, 0 - отмена. ")
    if dia == '0':
        print("See you later!")
        

con = True

while con:
    question1()
    question2()
    break
```

Comment: Используй функцию.

Comment: Если вы создали переменную, т.е. занесли в нее некоторое значение, то она будет жить "вечно". И использовать (т.е. применять справа от оператора присваивания, или в качестве параметра функций) вы ее можете в любой точке вашего кода,  - разумеется после (ниже) места ее определения. (Про переменную "вызывать" не говорят, говорят -  "использовать". А "вызывают" - функции, т.е. то, что само по себе может возвратить -  но не хранить -  некоторое значение. )

Comment: Может, вы хотите, как в Паскале, описать вверху переменные, а инициализировать потом? Нет, так нельзя. Переменная в Питоне создаётся, когда вы присваиваете её какое-то значение.

Comment: Что значит "не вызывалась к примеру там где она прописана"? Не очень понятно

Comment: переменная и так "вызывается" там, где она "вызывается", а не там, где она "прописана"

Comment: karashal, я пробовал помещать это в функцию и вызывать её, но мне нужно было получить значение из этой переменной, а как известно, область видимость переменной этого не позволяет сделать. Я наверное прикреплю код, для лучшего понимания. Я хотел воспользоваться значениями этой переменной(которые в неё поместятся) в цикле, но он не видит эту переменную. А мне нужно чтобы value_1 вызывалась когда пользователь выберет действие. В коде надеюсь будет немного яснее о чём я говорю.

Comment: CrazyElf, Имеется ввиду, что я хочу объявить эту переменную и поместить в неё 
 значение input('') в начале кода, а уже потом ею пользоваться. Просто я пишу этот инпут, он сразу же срабатывает. Конкретнее: просит ввести число 1 и 2. А мне это нужно только тогда, когда пользователь этого захочет.

Answer (score 0):

- Вы можете описать функцию в начале кода, а вызвать её в произвольном месте программы после. Хоть в середине, хоть в конце. Сработает функция в момент вызова, а описание будет, например, в начале кода. Собственно, у вас так и сделано.
- В вашем коде вы не видите содержание переменных, установленных функцией, потому что вы ничего не возвращаете из вызываемых функций. Возвращайте из функции нужные значения через `return` и присваивайте их переменным основной программы. И у вас всё будет.
- Можно использовать также указание `global` и сделать ваши локальные переменные внутри функции глобальными, но этого делать строго не рекомендуется. Это часто приводит к путанице и непрозрачности кода. В нормальном коде все параметры функция должна получать на вход в явном виде и все нужные результаты своей работы также возвращать в явном виде через `return`. Такие функции легко тестировать и есть некоторая гарантия, что они не "сломают" вам состояние вашей программы когда вы этого не ожидаете.

Пример кода:

```
def question2():
    value_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
    value_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')
    return value_1,value_2

...

val_1, val2 = question2()
```

Comment: CrazyElf, Я правильно понял, нужно сделать что-то вроде этого: def question2():
    value_1 = input('Введите первое число: ')
    return value_1
    value_2 = input('Введите второе число: ')
    return value_2                                                                                                                                 Или создать для двух переменных свою функцию и в конце писать              return value_1 а в другой return value_2?

Comment: @Daniil Добавил пример кода. Можно возвращать любое число переменных из функции, но сделать это можно только один раз, выполнится только один `return` из функции

Comment: CrazyElf, Спасибо за совет, я попробую всё это реализовать через цикл while, чтобы потом использовать больше чем один раз. Буду пробовать. Спасибо.